# Elasticsearch query operator

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to query elasticsearch using the URL in document. I've indexed product details along with its URL in ES. For example,

http://link/index/_search?q=http://www.amazon.in/Vera-Wang-Princess-Toilette-100-55ml

In the q parameter, I need to pass the link of the document I want to retrieve from the index.

Update:

I want to search using the product URL in the document. Here's my sample data.

"product_url" : "url",

"image_url" : "url",

"title" : "Vera-Wang-Princess-Toilette-100-55ml",

"affiliate_url" : "URL of the product",

"price1" : 3,669.50,

"price2" : 3,929

If there's no = in the product url then it works but if there is = then it displays null. I want to know how to pass the product url in the search operation. I'm using the below URI to search the document.
//http://localhost/index/_search?q=http://https://inen.strawberrynet.com/perfume/vera-wang/princess-eau-de-toilette-spray/55800/?trackid=7070500001&campaign=Google+-+PF&langboxoff=true&Currid=INR&gclid=CLy3kv2Il9QCFdKKaAodbzwOqQ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a sample document as well as the mapping of the field in which you've indexed the URL data?

Comment: It's preferable to update your question.

Comment: `The reserved characters in elasticsearch are: + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`... You need to escape these characters... https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters

Comment: I tried giving \ infront of = also but still it didn't work.